# Arboles en c++, estructuras no lineales

Tags: c++, estructuras-de-datos

Buenas noches quisiera saber cómo crear un arbol en C++ utilizando las operaciones:

> 1. -insert()
> 2. -Delate()
> 3. -isEmpty()
> 4. -size()
> 5. -depth()

Nota: No quiero llamar funciones. Quiero poder usar las 5 operaciones que les mencione, pero solo encuentro métodos que llaman a funciones.

Por ejemplo para las pilas en C++, está la librería  que me permite usar las operaciones

> 1. -push()
> 2. -pop()
> 3. -top()

Etc. sin la necesidad de crear y llamar funciones, quiero lo mismo, pero para un árbol.

Dejo el ejemplo de la pila para que me entiendan que es posible hacer la pila sin usar funciones utilizando las operaciones que les mencione. Y yo quiero lo mismo, pero para un árbol ya que el problema que tengo que resolver me pide usar por los menos las operaciones

> insert(), delete(), isEmpty() y printInOrder().

Pero no quieren que cree y llame funciones.

En fin aquí les dejo un problema anterior que resolví de una pila sin crear y llamar funciones.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stack>//con esta libreria puedo crear pilas sin necesidad de crear una funcion no se si exista una libreria especial para arboles.

using namespace std;

stack <int> pila; //En esta linea se crea la pila que almacenara datos de tipo entero <int> sin necesidad de crear una funcion

int main(){
    //Estas lineas permiten almacenar datos en la pila sin necesidad de llamar a una función utilizando .push() pero para el árbol me piden usar .insert() pero no se como se utiliza dicha operación 
    pila.push(8);
    pila.push(9);
    pila.push(7);
    
    cout<<pila.top()<<endl; //.top() permite mostrar el ultimo elemento de la pila sin necesidad de crear y llamar a una función
    pila.pop(); //.pop() permite eliminar el elemento de la pila sin necesidad de crear y llamar una función pero para el caso del árbol me piden usar .delate()
    cout<<pila.top()<<endl;
    pila.pop();
    cout<<pila.top()<<endl;
    pila.pop();
    
    /*
    En este caso los datos ingresado son 8,9,7 y al ser una pila cuando lo imprime muestra 7,9,8 pero lo importante es que se creo la pila
    sin necesidad de crear y llamar funciones, lo mismo quiero hacer pero para arboles binarios utilizando las propiedades de los arboles:
    1.-insert(): Insertar un elemento en un árbol
    2.-Delate(): Eliminar un elemento de un árbol
    3.-isEmpty(): Comprobar si un árbol está vacío
    4.-size(): Contar el número de nodos
    5.-depth(): Calcular la altura de un árbol
    */
    
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Creo que tenes una confusion grave... al hacer stack.push estas llamando a la funcion push que esta dentro de la libreria de clase stack...

Comment: entonces.. vos lo que estas pidiendo es si hay una libreria para arboles?

Comment: Mmm, c++ creo que no viene con una librera para manejar árboles, en caso de que exista será de un tercero, así que bien pudieras crear tu mismo tu propia clase árbol e implementar los métodos que necesitas

Comment: quisiera saber cómo crear un arbol en C++ utilizando las operaciones:

1.-insert() 2.-Delate() 3.-isEmpty() 4.-size() 5.-depth()

Comment: Crear un árbol lleva tiempo, tu sabes algo de árboles?

Comment: Se crear arboles sencillos usando funciones pero me piden usar 1.-insert() 2.-Delate() 3.-isEmpty() 4.-size() 5.-depth()

Comment: Bueno, es que esas funciones vas a tener que crearlas tu, ya que en c++ no existen

Comment: Estas seguro, lo que pasa es que hasta hace poco yo siempre habia utilizado funciones para hacer pilas hasta hace poco que aprendi que existia la libreria <stack>. Por ejemplo aun que cambie un poco de tema te pregundo ¿Existe una libreria para crear colas y cuales son las propiedades que se pueden usar en las colas?

Comment: Socio, busca en internet librerías para manejar árboles en c++ y así sales de dudas o aquí mismo en el buscador del sitio busca preguntas que tengan que ver con lo que pides

Comment: ya lo busque los mismo hice cuando me pidieron usar las pilas y me tarde demasiado de hecho es lo que estoy haciendo, pero nada.

Comment: Si lo que estas pidiendo es una libreria, entonces debo cerrar la pregunta...

Comment: En tu perfil tienes dos preguntas, entra a tu primera pregunta y pregúntale esas dudas al que te ayudo

Comment: No estoy pidiendo una libreria estoy pidiendo crear un arbol pero sin utilizar funciones, crear el arbol utilizando las propiedades 1.-insert() 2.-Delate() 3.-isEmpty() 4.-size() 5.-depth()

Comment: eso que decis, son funciones.. lo que estas pidiendo, es una libreria que lo haga por vos... o sea, estas preguntando si alguien conoce una libreria que ya tenga escritas esas funciones

Comment: Se alargó esta pila de comentarios pero pues... el fondo de lo que comenta @gbianchi es que preguntar cómo hago sin código propio y trayendo el ejemplo de la pila, termina siendo equivalente a preguntar "hay algo como eso?". Es todo. Varios acá sabemos que es demorado porque también nos correspondió ese ejercicio en clase...

Answer (score 1):

> Por ejemplo para las pilas en C++, está la librería  que me permite usar las operaciones
>
> > 1. -push()
> > 2. -pop()
> > 3. -top()
>
> Etc. sin la necesidad de crear y llamar funciones, quiero lo mismo, pero para un árbol.

Tienes un buen lío montado en tu cabeza. No tienes ni idea de lo que es una función.

---

En [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) existen cuatro tipos de funciones:

|  | Libres | Miembro |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Dinámica | `void F();` | `void Objeto::F();` |
| Expresión constante | `constexpr void F();` | `constexpr void Objeto::F();` |

Las operaciones que mencionas son funciones, en concreto **funciones miembro** del objeto pila.

Por lo tanto es completa y absolutamente imposible que puedas redactar un árbol sin llamar a funciones, eso que llamas *operaciones* **son funciones**.

Si quieres redactar un árbol te aconsejo lo siguiente:

1. Crea un objeto árbol que gestione los nodos, de este objeto colgarán todas las funciones (*operaciones*) que requieres:

   ```
   template <typename T>
   class Arbol {
       void insert(T);
       void Delate();
       bool isEmpty() const;
       int size() const;
       int depth() const;
   }
   ```
2. En el ámbito privado de tu objeto árbol, crea el nodo:

   ```
   template <typename U>
   struct Nodo {
       U data;
       Nodo *left = nullptr, *right = nullptr;
   };
   ```
3. Redacta las funciones (*operaciones*) que requieres.